Dell XPS 9320 Ubuntu 22.04 camera not working after update
Ubuntu 22.04 automatically installed updates on 8/14/2024 and the built-in camera immediately stopped working. It appears in the menu for applications and the "Additional drivers" tab in "Software Updater" shows that the Dell drivers are selected (see below), but all applications (e.g., Zoom, etc.) just show a black image. I'm not sure, but I think the relevant update logs are below.
Any suggestions?
Start-Date: 2024-08-14  07:15:59
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.132'
Install: linux-tools-common:amd64 (5.15.0-118.128, automatic), linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-ipu6-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic), linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3, automatic)
Upgrade: containerd.io:amd64 (1.7.19-1, 1.7.20-1), docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:27.1.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy, 5:27.1.2-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (127.0.6533.88-1, 127.0.6533.119-1), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.6), linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), docker-buildx-plugin:amd64 (0.16.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy, 0.16.2-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy), docker-ce:amd64 (5:27.1.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy, 5:27.1.2-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), docker-ce-rootless-extras:amd64 (5:27.1.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy, 5:27.1.2-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.5.0.45.45~22.04.1, 6.8.0-40.40~22.04.3), ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3), python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.6), code:amd64 (1.92.0-1722473020, 1.92.1-1723066302), python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.6), apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5, 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.6), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.481.2, 1.481.3)
End-Date: 2024-08-14  07:16:38

Start-Date: 2024-08-14  07:16:53
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.132'
Remove: linux-modules-ipu6-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-modules-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-headers-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-modules-ivsc-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-44:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1), linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-44-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-44.44~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-08-14  07:16:58


